# RGB Illuminated Potentiometers

Tags: led, potentiometer, led-driver, rgb

I'm currently designing a circuit using Alpha [RV141F-40-20BL-B50K](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/13/V141F-1522277.pdf) Potentiometers which feature a clear shift into which a 3mm LED can be inserted.

My initial plan was to just fit a [WS2812B](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) underneath each chip for simple RGB addressing of each potentiometer. Unfortunately, there is only a 0.9mm gap underneath the pot, which won't fit the 1.6mm 5050 package. Additionally, I am worried about light leaking from one pot to another if the led is not properly inserted into the shaft.

My second approach was to use an external driver (e.g. TLC5940) and a 3mm RGB led until I realised that "real" 3mm RGB LEDs don't exist.

Does anybody know about an equivalent of a 3mm led as an smd package, any other widely available clear shaft potentiometers or does anybody have any other thoughts/ideas regarding the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately sourcing questions are off topic here

Comment: Another option, route a hole under the potentiometer and mount the led on the back side. I've seen it done with SMD and the led was mounted upside down.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to EE, but I believe it's less a sourcing and more a design question, isn't it? If anything I'm more looking for a type of package or idea for design than an actual part

Comment: @RonBeyer The idea sounds neat, but a 5050 package only has pins at the bottom, so I'd need another package or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to select an LED that was compatible with that type of mounting.

Comment: You could make the 5050 work though by gluing it down, and using wire wrap to solder to the pads, I wouldn't do that for high volume boards but a few wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: something like this may work ... https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12986 ... drill a 5 mm hole under the pot ... shave down the end of the LED so that it fits into the pot ... paint sides of LED to prevent light leakage

Comment: My current idea is to either make a square hole and basically make the whole 5050 disappear inside the PCB, giving me more or less flush contacts on the bottom or maybe using APA102 2020 Leds which seem to be exactly 0.9mm high... @jsotola that's also a neat idea, thank you! shaving down might be a bit of pain :/

Comment: there is no reason to make square holes ... drill a 3 mm hole and use a short piece of light pipe to bring the light from back of the board into the potentiometer shaft ... https://www.mouser.ca/Optoelectronics/LED-Indication/LED-Light-Pipes/_/N-b1d20

Comment: i think that this actually clips onto the SMD ... https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bivar-inc/VLP-650-F/492-2287-ND/4500883

Comment: The idea with the square hole was mainly to be able to use the WS2812B Addressable LEDs without funky pin-bending, by just making the contacts flush with the bottom pads and bridging the 0.2mm manufacturing tolerance... the 3mm hole + light pipe idea is super neat, but it would require the use of other LEDs... maybe I can use the square hole & just glue the light pipe directly onto the 5050 (+ coat in black paint?)